# Authentication in to the site (MVC4) using azure storage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, authorization, storage

As a mechanism for authentication azure stodge opportunity to give a token of limited duration. on record in the user's session and in the process of working with the user to the site to check the validity of it. At the end simply offers the user to log in again.
May suggest how this scheme is correct? 
Is there a similar solution for logging on using the azure stodge ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for token authentication you'd better use OAuth or OAuth2. It does exactly what you want, but you can create a action filter to achieve the same functionality.

Here's a sample with a WebApi Controller, it's easy to switch to a mvc controller. Basically you won't have the token in a http header but in a querystring.

```
[AuthKey]
public class PurchaseController : ApiController
{
     //methods
}

public class AuthKeyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{        
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Contains("auth-key") == false)
            actionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        else
        {
            var token = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("auth-key").First();

            var sessionServices = new SessionServices();
            var session = sessionServices.SearchSessionByAuthKey(token);

            if (session == null || session.expirationDate < DateTime.Now)
            {
                actionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                return;
            }

            var controller = actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller;

            if (controller is BaseController)
            {
                var baseController = (BaseController)controller;
                baseController.SetThreadLocalSession(session);
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        }
    }
}
```